# ZipEntry UTF-8 charset

Tags: java, utf-8, zip

I'm creating some zip files inside a main zip (name finalZip.zip) using Java, and these filenames has characters like áóç. When I try to create a zip file, the name of the file is wrong. For example, when 3-ORDINÁRIA-2017-05-03.zip, it comes 3-ORDIN+üRIA-2017-05-03.zip

```
String zipName= number + "- ORDINÁRIA -" + sdf.format(sdfComplete.parse(date.getTime()) + ".zip";

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
try {
  bos = createZipFile(); // populate each zipFile with some images
  // generating zip file, ex: 6-ORDINÁRIA-2017-03-15.zip
  zipFinal.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipName));
  zipFinal.write(bos.toByteArray());
  zipFinal.closeEntry();
}

...
```

I want the zip files with UTF-8 charset. How can I solve this charset problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use the  `public ZipOutputStream(OutputStream out, Charset charset)` constructor to specify the charset for both the entry names and comments.

The method's javadoc :

> Creates a new ZIP output stream.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **out** the actual output stream
>
> **charset** the charset to be used to encode the entry names and comments

For example this uses the UTF-8 charset :

```
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(bos, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: My ZipOutputStream accepts only 1 constructor (OutputStream). I think my java version is kind of old

Comment: Maybe. It is available since 1.7.You are under ?

Comment: I'm on 1.8, but when I import the StandardCharsets, the UTF_8 constant is undefined

Comment: try it : `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` I think that you have imported  the `sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets` class. The `sun` packages use should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still has that problem or the data into the file cannot be utf-8

- First the invoque method must be like these: 
  `final ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(baos, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
- When insert data and it cant be encoded:
  `zip.write(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));`